# Python dictionary in string format

Tags: python, string, dictionary, join, lis

I have a dictionary like this

```
verdict = {'1': 'PASS', '2': 'FAIL}
```

I want to print this dictionary in a string format without using for loop.
output:

```
1: PASS
2: FAIL
```

So far I have tried this:

```
print(*verdict.items(), sep='\n')

Output:
('1', 'PASS')
('2', 'FAIL)
```

but not getting the actual results

Is there any way through which I can achieve the desired output?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: have edited the question. Kindly check.

Comment: Not everything can be done with just `print()` you will need a loop and string formatting (f-string or `.format()`).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways I can think of doing this

Method 1:

```
print("\n".join([f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in verdict.items()]))
```

Method 2:

```
for k, v in verdict.items():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')
```